# Find the canonical form of the elliptic equation $u_{xx}-2u_{xy}+5u_{yy}=0.$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

> Find the canonical form of the elliptic equation $$u_{xx}-2u_{xy}+5u_{yy}=0.$$

**Attempt.** Since $a=1,~b=-2,~c=5$, we get $\displaystyle b^2-4ac=-16<0$, so the equation is indeed elliptic. The characteristic equation yields:
$$\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{b\pm i\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}{2a} = -1\pm 2i$$ and $y+1\pm 2i x=c$.
Setting $ \xi(x,y):=y+1-2 ix,~~\eta(x,y):=y+1+2ix$
and
$$\mu=\frac{\xi+\eta}{2} = y+1,~~~\nu=\frac{\xi-\eta}{2i} =-2x,$$

then the given equation becomes

$$Α(\mu,\nu)u_{\mu\mu}+B(\mu,\nu)u_{\mu\nu}+C(\mu,\nu)u_{\nu \nu} +D(\mu,\nu) u_{\mu}+E(\mu,\nu) u_{\nu}+F(\mu,\nu) u=G(\mu,\nu)$$

where

\begin{eqnarray}
A(\mu,\nu) &=& a\mu_x^2+b\mu_x\mu_y+c\mu_y^2=5,\nonumber\\
B(\mu,\nu) &=& 2a\mu_x\nu_x+b(\mu_x\nu_y+\mu_y\nu_x)+2c\mu_y\nu_y=4,\nonumber\\
C(\mu,\nu) &=& a\nu_x^2+b\nu_x\nu_y+c\nu_y^2=4,\nonumber\\
D(\mu,\nu) &=& a\mu_{xx}+b\mu_{xy}+c\mu_{yy}+d\mu_x+e\mu_y=0,\nonumber\\
E(\mu,\nu) &=& a\nu_{xx}+b\nu_{xy}+c\nu_{yy}+d\nu_x+e\nu_y=0,\nonumber\\
F(\mu,\nu) &=& f =0 ~~and~~ G(\mu,\nu)~=~g=0.\nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

**Question**: according to the general theory, the canonical form should be
$u_{\mu\mu}+u_{\nu \nu}=H(\mu,\nu,u,u_\mu,u_\nu)$, which is not the case here. I cannot find the flaw, though.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Making a change of variables such as

$$
\cases{\eta = x + \frac{\lambda-1}{5\lambda-1} y\\
\xi = x+\lambda y
}
$$

we obtain

$$
4u_{\eta\eta}+(1-5\lambda)^2u_{\xi\xi}=0
$$

NOTE

The trick follows:

making the generic change of variables

$$
\cases{\eta = x + c_1 y\\
\xi = x+c_2 y
}
$$

we arrive at

$$
\left(5 c_2^2-2 c_2+1\right) u_{\xi\xi}+2 \left(c_1 \left(5 c_2-1\right)-c_2+1\right) u_{\eta\xi}+\left(5 c_1^2-2 c_1+1\right) u_{\eta\eta}=0
$$

then we choose $c_2 = \lambda, c_1 = \frac{\lambda-1}{5\lambda-1}$. Here $\lambda\in \mathbb{R},\lambda\ne \frac 15$.

Finally, choosing $(1-5\lambda)^2 = 4$ we have for $\lambda =\{ -\frac 15,\frac{3}{5}\}$

$$
4u_{\eta\eta}+4u_{\xi\xi}=0\Rightarrow u_{\eta\eta}+u_{\xi\xi}=0
$$

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot derive that.

Comment: Attached a NOTE explaining the result.

Comment: Okay, everything is clear now (+1). Thanks!

Comment: Typical. That gives (of course):
$$
\begin{cases}
\eta = x + \frac{3}{5}y \\
\xi = x - \frac{1}{5}y
\end{cases}
\quad \mbox{or} \quad
\begin{cases}
\xi = x + \frac{3}{5}y \\
\eta = x - \frac{1}{5}y
\end{cases}
$$